# What is $\lim\limits_{i\to 0} \frac{2^n}{\frac{(n+1)\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta } - \frac{(n-1)\sin((n-1)\theta)}{\sin\theta }} $?

Tags: calculus

What is $$\lim\limits_{i\to 0} \dfrac{2^n}{\frac{(n+1)\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta } - \frac{(n-1)\sin((n-1)\theta)}{\sin\theta }} $$ where $$\theta=\frac{i\pi}{n} $$ The second page of [this document](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/15/2/156.full.pdf) says, that it's $$\frac{2^{n-2}}{n}$$ but I'm at a complete loss as to how to come to this conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too hard to show that

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin{mx}}{nx} = \frac{m}{n}$$

Thus

$$\lim\limits_{i\to 0} \dfrac{2^n}{\frac{(n+1)\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta } - \frac{(n-1)\sin((n-1)\theta)}{\sin\theta }} = \frac{2^n}{(n+1)^2-(n-1)^2} = \frac{2^n}{4n} = \frac{2^{n-2}}{n}$$